# How to Install SiteMinder web agent on AIX 7.1

Tags: aix

please help me on this to install on AIX 7.1

**CA SiteMinder Web Agent - 6.0.535.858 6QMR5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/sametime/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.help.sametime.advanced.doc/stv_adm_t_install_siteminder_webagent.html)?

Or [this](https://support.ca.com/cadocs/0/h003471e.pdf)?